# If string contains month name then convert to number

Tags: php

I have a string `$str` that contains various date formats (I don't really have control of that!), is it possible to change any month names to numbers?

These are some of the formats coming out:

- 2020-09-14
- 14-feb-2018
- 14-march-2018

Would it then be possible to change all the date formats to the first example?

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yah  by this

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($old_date));
```

Eg.

```
$new_date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('14-feb-2018'));
$new_date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('14-march-2018'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function convertMonthToInt( $date ) {

    $date_bits = explode( "-", $date );

    $months = array(

        "january" => 1,

        //etc etc

    );

    if( is_string( $date_bits[ 1 ] ) !== true ) {

        return $date_bits[ 1 ];

    }

    return $months[ strtolower( $date_bits[ 1 ] ) ];

};

convertMonthToInt( "14-march-2018" );
```

Comment: What are you doing here? Have you tested your code?Seems you have not! And why reinventing the wheel again? This should be a 1 line code. This sis why `strtotime` exisits

Comment: Corrected it the mistake. Turned around the array.

Comment: Thank you for your exceptionally helpful feedback!